# Store Object-Oriented Functions as Object Member Function or as General Function With Object Reference as a Parameter?

Tags: c++, function, class

Language is C++. Apologies for a wordy title, but what I'm essentially asking is which one of these methods here is better:

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
     int myValue;

     myClass(int myInputValue) : myValue(myInputValue) {}

     void myClassFunction() {
          std::cout << myValue << std::endl;
     }
}

myClass myObject(10);

myObject.myClassFunction();
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
public:
     int myValue;

     myClass(int myInputValue) : myValue(myInputValue) {}
}

void myClassFunction(myClass& inputObject) {
     std::cout << inputObject.myValue << std::endl;
}

myClass myObject(10);

myClassFunction(myObject);
```

Obviously my example is far too simple for this difference to even matter, but what if I'm working at large scales and with large data structures?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Your 2nd case won't work as posted since myValue is private. Which general approach is better  probably depends on the situation and the nature of what you are doing.

Comment: First way also won't work since all members are private.